# How to validate multiple inputs in in Unity. Inputs are in a list of CUSTOM CLASS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

In Mount Blade: Warband Quick Battle Mode, The user is allowed to choose the army composition as shown in the picture:

[image: Mount Blade Warband Quick Battle Screen]

As the user slides one of the sliders, the other ones automatically move to a reasonable value.

I want to do something similar But In the Unity Inspector. I have a class that contains a GameObject and a byte slider (Using Range Attribute):
[image: My Inspector]

How can I achieve similar results, for the spawn chance of every ***grid item***?

> **Spawn Chance** is a `byte` *.*

I used the `OnValidate` function. I obtained the spawn chances as follows :

```cs
// the sum of all spawn chances should be 100
List<byte> spawnChances = new List<byte>();
foreach (Spawnable item in gridItems) {
    spawnChances.Add(item.spawnChance);
}
if (spawnChances.Count > 0) {
    byte sum = 0;
    foreach (byte chance in spawnChances) {
        sum += chance;
    }
    if (sum != 100) {
        foreach (Spawnable item in gridItems) {
            item.spawnChance = (byte)(item.spawnChance / sum * 100);
            // if i do this, when i change the value
            // the editor snaps it to 100
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you know [OnValidate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) is Editor-ONLY ?

Comment: Yes, If there is a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting values between 0 and 1, which you multiply with 100 here:

```
item.spawnChance = (byte)(item.spawnChance / sum * 100);
```

but it snaps to 0 or 100. That's because `item.spawnChance / sum` will be 0 or 1.

spawnChance is a byte (whole number like int) and dividing that will not result in a fraction like 0.34. You need a float for this operation.

Simple fix, cast the spawnChance to float before dividing by sum:

```
item.spawnChance = (byte)((float)item.spawnChance / sum * 100);
```

Comment: I tested it. It worked but when tow of the values becomes zero, it starts snapping again. I think this is because the sum of all the "spawnChance"s should be 100.

Comment: Make sure not all values are 0, because then `sum` will be 0 and you get `cannot divide by 0` error.

Comment: You could catch this case `item.spawnChance = sum == 0 ? 0 : (byte)(item.spawnChance / sum * 100f);` also note that using `100f` you already have a `float` and don't need the explicit castings - imho looks a bit cleaner ;)